# Excel Formula: Excluding some columns from formula based on header

Tags: excel, macos, excel-formula

I have a COUNTIF formula that counts a particular value across a range of columns in each row. However, I would like to exclude the cell values in a particular column based on the column header.

For example, I need to count the number of cells that contain the value 'NS' across a range 'C:Z' for each row in the worksheet. However, I need to exclude the values in cells that have a column header 'RC'. The challenge is, I cannot control where these 'RC' columns appear in the range. Therefore, I am looking for some mechanism through which I can check whether the column header is 'RC' or not, and if it is, then exclude the cell values from the COUNTIF formula.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: What about COUNTIFS?

Comment: I am using a COUNTIF to count the number of 'NS' values across the range 'C:Z' in each row. However, like I said, I am trying to exclude all the cells which belong to a column that has an 'RC' header. Is there anyway to reflect this condition within the COUNTIF formula as well?

Comment: What is your exact COUNTIF formula? Are you looking for something like `=COUNTIFS(C1:Z1,"<>RC",C2:Z2,"NS")`?

Comment: =COUNTIF(SheetName!C3:Z3, "NS") and this formula is copied down to all the filled rows in the worksheet.

Comment: @BigBen - what you suggested doesn't appear to be working. It still includes all the cells that are in columns with an 'RC' header.

Comment: No repro (based on the screenshot below). Can you [edit] your question with the exact formula you're using and maybe a screenshot? Or is the text in your header actually 'RC', with the single quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=COUNTIFS(C$1:Z$1,"<>RC",C3:Z3,"NS")
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

As noted by [@JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv), if you are just looking for a single formula to count all instances (i.e. not row-by-row), you can use `=SUMPRODUCT((C1:Z1<>"RC")*(C2:Z100="NS"))`, changing the `100` to your last row as necessary.

Comment: Isn't OP looking for a small change: `=SUMPRODUCT((C1:Z1<>"RC")*(C2:Z100="NS"))` or whichever may be the last row? That way youll get the full count of cells containing "NS" in all rows where header <> "RC"

Comment: @JvdV I was interpreting "=COUNTIF(SheetName!C3:Z3, "NS") and this formula is copied down to all the filled rows in the worksheet". But that would be an option yes if OP wanted a one-and-done formula.

Comment: Ah right, yeah. I was just wondering since OP says this wasn't what he was after. If it's per row, then sure that's a fine answer :)

Comment: Feel free to put it in as an alternative. Your explaination makes perfect sence. And if not, than the question is stated in a way it can be misunderstood through this sentence: "I need to count the number of cells that contain the value 'NS' across a range 'C:Z' for each row in the worksheet."

Comment: You're right - I do need it per row and should have made it more clear. Either way, your solution works - @BigBen.